# Antd Select drop down opens automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

In my react component I have an Antd Selector component to select the dropdown. After selecting value from the dropdown, if I wait on the screen for 30-50 seconds the dropdown automatically opens again with the (focus on the selected dropdown) **without being clicked**. What might be the issue?

```
                          <Select
                            placeholder="Select"
                            style={{
                              minWidth: "50px",
                              width: `${selectWidth * 2}%`,
                            }}
                            value={valSelected}
                            onChange={(val) => {
                              setValSelected(val);
                            }}
                          >
                            {valSlicerOptions.map((option) => (
                              <Select.Option key={option} value={option}>
                                {option}
                              </Select.Option>
                            ))}
                          </Select>
```

Comment: The code written here is the correct code. I also implemented same code and it's working fine for me.

Comment: maybe you can add codepen/stackblitz? that would be easy for the community to help

Comment: please provide more details about your code.. perhaps this issue it not even related to this select component